# CSS Alignment Not Working

Tags: html, css

For the life of me, I can't solve this issue. Hopefully this will be easy for one of you awesome people.

At this point, I'm mostly trying to get the "Salon Voicemail" image lined correctly in "wide" mode to the top (images are all rough – I'm not worried about that):

http://saviourssalon.com/test/063/

The separation between images is also too small – I think I was experimenting with using different sized images later, but I don't think that would have solved this problem anyway.

The last time I asked a question here, people mentioned using Firebug. I used the equivalent tool in Safari, but it didn't really seem to help in this case.

Here's the most important part of the CSS:

```
img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: auto;
}

#hero_wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

box { 
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 466px;
}
```

Here's the corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="contact_wrapper">  
  <box>
    <div>
      <img src="images/big_type_v2_011_06.jpg">
      <img src="images/big_type_v2_011_08.jpg">
    </div>
  </box>
  <box>
    <div>
      <img src="images/big_type_v2_011_12.jpg">
      <img src="images/big_type_v2_011_13.jpg">
    </div>
  </box>        
</div>
```

Full CSS is [here](http://saviourssalon.com/test/063/stylesheets/main.css).

Comment: Why are you putting text content into images? And why are you inventing your own HTML elements (`<box>`)? I think you should invest a little more time in learning some basics of HTML and CSS …

Comment: If you want to align inline elements such as images vertically, then the CSS property to use for that is `vertical-align`. And `auto` is not a valid value for any of the `padding`-properties.

Comment: I know my use of <box> is weird, but for whatever reason, it seemed to give me better results. In a previous version of this post, I linked to different versions of the site I had made, but the post got voted down, so I tried streamlining it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the `vertical-align` property to the following CSS rule:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

You can get better control of image spacing if you use `display: inline-block` on your images that way top/bottom margins will have the desired effect.

For illustrative purposes:

[image]

Comment: Aha! I had previously tried `display:block`, but it was giving me bad results. Wasn't aware of `inline-block`, thanks.